# component re-rendering on from different slices of state after dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In react / redux  (with toolkit):

I've got components re-rendering - triggered on a redux action.
acting on a different slice;

so my DOM structure is as follows

```
<DataWindow>

<DataSelector />

<DataIncoming />

<DataCardContainer />

</DataWindow>
```

Selector receives and renders a prop which is set by clicking on an item in incoming;
However - clicking on an item in incoming causes 'DataCardContainer' to re-render;

DataWindow is nothing but the jsx above

DataSelector takes a 'logic' slice - and gets the 'dataSelector' property and displays it;

```
function DataSelector(props){
    const logic = useSelector(LOGIC);

    return(
        <div className="DataSelector">
            selector {logic.dataSelector}
        </div>
    )
}
```

DataIncomming is a list displaying;

```
function DataIncoming(props){
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const incomingData = useSelector(selectNoData); //from jobs
    const incoming = incomingData.map(x=><div key ={x.jID} className="incDataCard" onClick={()=>dispatch(setDataSelector(x.jID))}>{x.JobNum} {x.JobName} </div>)



    return(
        <div className="DataIncoming">
            incoming {incoming}
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
function DataCardContainer(){    
    const madeData = useSelector(selectMadeData); //from the slice 'data'
    const jobData = useSelector(selectJobs); // from the slice 'jobs'
    const dataCards = madeData.map(x=>{
        const foundJob = jobData.find(y=>y.jID === x.attachedJID);
        console.log(foundJob,"founjob"); //this logs when i click on any of the 'incDataCard' rendered in DataIncoming
        return(<DataCard key={x.DataKey} props={x} jobInfo={foundJob} />)})


    return(
        <div className="DataCardContainer">
           {dataCards}
        </div>
    )


}
```

Which uses the selector for jobs (selectNoData) and displays them in a list - that you can click on which will run the following dispatch from the logic slice;

```
    setDataSelector:(state,action)=>{
        state.dataSelector=action.payload;
        console.log("yay, setDataSelector");
        return state;
    }
```

The thing that confuses me - is DataCardContainer and DataWindow do not touch the logic slice at all -

so my question is: why is the component DataCardContainer re-rendering on every dispatch from DataIncoming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

useSelector() will cause re-renders if the value it produces has changed. When returning an object be aware that **unless it's the same object by reference equality the component will re-render even if the objects properties are the same**. You can get around this by always returning the same object.

In your case the easiest way to only select the state needed ist to tell useSelector to do a shallow equal comparison instead of a reference equality comparison. useSelector accepts a comparator function as the second argument:

```
import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const user = useSelector(
    ({user}) => ({
        id: user.id
        name: user.name
        lastName: user.lastName
    }),
    shallowEqual
);
```

Comment: but I'm still confused: does useSelector() cause not just the selected state,but the entire state to re-render? if it is just the selected state... I don't understand how what you are proposing is a solution at all?... again... the key thing NOTHING in the selected slice on one those two components change anything in the third. the only things acted upon is the logic slice, and yet the job slice re-renders on the dispatch to the logic slice. the component in question is displaying a different part of the state object. and yet - that part of the state re-renders? is this right?

Comment: Redux stores everything in a single state object. every change on State useSelector function does a check if anything changes, remember it does object reference check(this is the key), even if your values are same but object reference might have changed based on the structure of the state. if you want to override you need to pass shallowEqual in useselector. if you pass shallowEqual, the selector will not do reference equality check, it will do value check.

Comment: copy. I had assumed that the default behavior then was only the part of the state that is being changed updates... not the entire state object.

Comment: shallow equals does not seem to work... adding in all shallowequals in useselectors does nothing - edit. i'm an idiot. it works.